# Затруднение с написанием простого алгоритма задания вероятностей

Tags: c++, теория-вероятностей

Пишу программу для бросков кубика с несимметричными гранями (следовательно, вероятность выпадения каждой из граней отличается друг от друга), поручил пользователю задать вероятности. Однако, программа работает неверно, что-то с циклами, навести порядок не получается. Помогите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 cout << " Количество бросков rand():" << setw(10) << n; 
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    switch (buff)
    {
    case 0:
        buff = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < kubik.nodes; ++i)
        {

            cout << "Введите вероятность выпадения грани "  << i+1 << " в % от 0 до " << buff-buff_ <<endl; 
            cin >> buff_; //процент выпадения
            if (buff_ < 0 || buff_ > buff-buff_){ 
            cout << "Введено неверное значение" << endl;
            --i;
            } else {    
                //buff -= buff_; //процент, который остался
                for (int i = buff_z; i < buff_z + buff_; ++i) //забиваем массив структуры значениями
                {
                kubik.value[i] = buff;
                }
                buff_z += buff_; //от какого значения будет заполняться массив

            }

        }
    break;
    case 1:
            buff = kubik.nodes;
            int *points = new int [buff];
            for(int i = 0; i < kubik.nodes; ++i)
        {
                points[i] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: `//buff -= buff_; //процент, который остался`

Comment: С этим еще хуже

Comment: потому, что выше неверно считается) откуда брали код?)

Comment: Корявое самосочинительство. Есть полная версия кода программы

Comment: в каждой итерации buff нужно уменьшать на введеное значение, но эта строчка почему-то закоментирована

Comment: Раскоментировал - логика вообще нарушилась.

Comment: Значит кривая логика и ее нужно править. Нельзя неправильную логику исправить, удалив правильную инструкцию.

Comment: Часть программы с симметричными гранями работает на ура. Что здесь.... непонятно https://pastebin.com/FBmyPzAc - код программы